# how to set meta tag dynamic from database in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

`ViewData["ChildPageMetaConent"] = lstPageMetaContentChilds;` // from this line i get data from database and set to ViewData .

Example : in `ViewData["ChildPageMetaConent"]`  have list class. You can check in Image. 
[image]

And on Master.cshtml I am accessing `ViewData["ChildPageMetaConent"]` variable and gointo to write on
page but its print on page like a text .
[image]

And on HTMl its look like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer.

Need to Use  `@Html.Raw(string)`

so it print exact html tag on page.